# Comment Opening and Closing Brackets (with ReSharper?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.1

Does anyone know if there's a way in Visual Studio 2010 with ReSharper 6.1 to comment out the selected lines of code with their closing brackets - or simply to comment out both the highlighted opening bracket and it's corresponding closing bracket? Here's an example of what I mean:

```
if(something) {
  do(this);
}
```

I am looking for a hot-key so that when `if(something) {` is selected, it will comment out `if(something) {` and `}`, preferably fixing the tabs once commented like so:

```
// if(something) {
do(this);
//}
```

Comment: Theoretically you could write a replace pattern (ReSharper->Tools->Pattern Catalog). But (at least in ReSharper 5.1.3) comment signs (*//*) in *Replace pattern* text field are ignored.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with search and replace patterns - with a ReSharper plug-in maybe.

Comment: Don't have an answer, but I think it is a great idea. Would also come in handy for try blocks sometimes. Please make sure you suggest it to Jetbrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't entirely what you're after, but it's pretty close:

Highlight the code inside the `if` statement by placing the cursor at one brace and hitting `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `]`.

Now hit `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `Left Arrow`. This will move the code 'left', i.e. outside of the if statement.

You don't need to comment the `if` statement out after this because it's empty.

Note that you can also move code 'right' to put it back in the `if` statement later.

Comment: Not bad. This doesn't exactly work in JS. You can keep hitting `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Right Arrow` to get the whole thing selected, and then `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `Up Arrow` to move the code outside of the if... but it's a little kludgey.